# Loading external images in WPF

Tags: wpf, windows, vb.net, xaml

I am building an application using WPF for Windows 8 in VB.NET and I need to load several images from the disk.
I don't want to add the images as a reference to the project, I just want to load them as is.

I already studied the ["Imaging Overview"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748873.aspx) at MSDN and several other articles over the internet but nothing solved my problem.

I used both XAML and code but nothing worked. I can't get the image presented.

> ```
> Dim myimage As New Image
> myimage.Width = 200
> Dim bitmapimage As New BitmapImage()
> bitmapimage.UriSource = New Uri("C:\Users\MyName\Documents\Database\image.jpg")
> myimage.Source = bitmapimage
> ```

XAML code:

> ```
> <Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
> <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="265" Margin="191,145,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="660">
>
> <Image.Source>
> <BitmapImage UriSource="C:\Users\MyName\Documents\Database\image.jpg"/>
> </Image.Source>
>
> </Image>
> </Grid>
> ```

When I load a referenced image (ie. Assets/Logo.png) it loads it correctly.
I also added all the necessary capabilities and declerations in the application manifest.

Comment: Can you give us the exact image you're trying to load ?

Comment: very odd behavior !! Try to reference that image to your project and see whether it loads ?

Comment: The image is not the issue and I am 100% positive about this. I used various images, in different resolutions and filetypes but still no luck. As I mentioned in my first post when I reference the images to my project they load but I don't want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Your XAML looks correct. Maybe the image path is invalid. However it could be written simpler like this:

```
<Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="265" Margin="191,145,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="660"
       Source="C:\Users\MyName\Documents\Database\image.jpg" />
```

The path string is automatically converted to an ImageSource instance.

In code you should use the [BitmapImage constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms602473%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) with Uri parameter. Otherwise you would have to call [BeginInit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.begininit%28v=vs.100%29) and [EndInit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.endinit%28v=vs.100%29).

```
Dim uri As New Uri("C:\Users\MyName\Documents\Database\image.jpg")
Dim bitmapimage As New BitmapImage(uri)
myimage.Source = bitmapimage
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, the syntax is correct, but unfortunately the problem still remains. I checked multiple times maybe I got the path wrong but that's not the issue. I also tried moving the image to an other location but still no good.

Comment: What if you try `C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Desert.jpg` as image path? Or - dumb question, i know - is your window (or the grid) perhaps smaller than that large margin `191,145`?

Comment: I tried multiple locations and formats for the image but none worked. Despite the grid being bigger than the image I also used smaller images and resolutions. Still nothing.